# Problem with memory allocation for allocatable array( real type )

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am new in Fortran programming so I need a help about allocatable arrays.

This is my simple code:

```
PROGRAM MY_SIMPLE_CODE

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: N_TMP, ALLOC_ERR, DEALLOC_ERR

REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: P_POT

WRITE( *,* ) "ENTER THE VALUE FOR N_TMP:"
 READ( *,* ) N_TMP

IF ( .NOT. ALLOCATED( P_POT) ) ALLOCATE( P_POT( N_TMP), STATUS = ALLOC_ERR )

IF ( ALLOC_ERR .NE. 0 ) STOP( "ERROR - ALLOCATION P_POT !!!")




IF ( ALLOCATED( P_POT) ) DEALLOCATE( P_POT, STATUS = DEALLOC_ERR )

IF ( DEALLOC_ERR .NE. 0 ) STOP( "ERROR - DEALLOCATION P_POT !!!")

END PROGRAM MY_SIMPLE_CODE
```

When I cobuild this code I got this error message:

`Allocate-object  is neither a data pointer nor an allocatable variable`

What is wrong with this code?

What kind of tricky stuff can be masked in this simple code?

IDE: Code::Blocks TDM_GCC_5 1 0

OS: Win 10 X64

Comment: I don't know about Code::Blocks, but I noticed that you use the `STATUS=` term in your allocation and deallocation. That's wrong, the keyword is `STAT=`.

Comment: It's probably what chw21 said, but why don't you post the error message for us to see?

Comment: @Monochromatic The question is now complete because I added error message.

Comment: You have two errors in your code.  First, as pointed out by @chw21, you want to `STAT=` instead of `STATUS`.  The error is correctly pointing at `STATUS`.  gfortran assumed if is a variable name.  Second, the `STOP` does not use parathesis.  Remove those.

Comment: @Steve I did not got warning from compiler that parathesis are syntax error. Why? Can I get a explanation because I want to know reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Steve said in the comment, the keyword for the status of allocation/deallocation is `STAT`, not `STATUS`. The error comes because the compiler doesn't recognize the name and thinks it is a variable.

Moreover, there is a syntax error because there must be at least a space between the `STOP` statement and the opening brace (or no braces at all).

```
IF ( .NOT. ALLOCATED( P_POT) ) ALLOCATE( P_POT( N_TMP), STAT = ALLOC_ERR )
IF ( ALLOC_ERR .NE. 0 ) STOP "ERROR - ALLOCATION P_POT !!!"
!(...)
IF ( ALLOCATED( P_POT) ) DEALLOCATE( P_POT, STAT = DEALLOC_ERR )
IF ( DEALLOC_ERR .NE. 0 ) STOP "ERROR - DEALLOCATION P_POT !!!"
```

Comment: It's not so much that `STOP ("x")` isn't allowed and must be written as `STOP "x"`, but that `STOP( "x" )` isn't allowed. The first is valid, the last isn't (placing of spaces).

Comment: This is weird... Fortran is not spaces-sensitive in general, specially with braces.

Comment: Not very weird: it's no different (in free form) from having to write `real x` rather than `realx` or `100 continue` rather than `100continue`, etc.  `if(x)` is allowed whereas `stop(x)` isn't, and the difference is that in the latter case the `(` is an integral part of the constant `(x)` - much as you can't have `stop1` instead of `stop 1`.